# How to add "Align bottom to: parent view" system constraint?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

Just created a demo single view controller project. Controller view contains collection view, and it contains cell view (orange). Cell view contains a view (selected inside) and I need to align it to bottom of cell view. However, when I select orange view inside cell view, press Ctrl and drag it to cell view I don't see "Align bottom to container view" or similar. There's only "Bottom Space to Container" selection and I'm not sure does it have the same behaviour:

[image]

And if I select "Bottom Space to Container" and don't get desired "Align bottom to parent" system constraint:

[image]

I need to add a new label in existing code base with auto layout, and the label must be positioned next to existing label that has "Align bottom to: parent cell" system constraint:

[image]

There's some setting "Bottom edges" if I select my new label and press align button icon at the bottom. However, this selection is disabled anyways and I assume this is user constraint but I need system constraint "Align bottom to: parent cell". Any suggestions why existing label has this constraint but I can't add a similar one to the new label?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding a `Bottom Space to Container` constraint is the correct way to go. It will align a view to a constant distance from it's parent's bottom edge. If you add that constraint and it doesn't result in the correct behaviour when resizing the view, there might be other constraints on the view that might need to be removed first (think a top constraint).

You could also align your label to the other label totally ignoring the container of course if you find that easier to setup.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any ideas why existing label in cell has "Align bottom to: parent cell" system constraint, but I can't find and add such constraint to the new label that is also in the same cell (same container)?

Comment: For me adding a `Bottom Space to Container` constraint by right-click-drag results in the correct "Bottom Space to: Superview" system constraint. Using the popovers you can achieve a similar effect by selecting the `Spacing to nearest neighbour` from the `Pin` popover (not the `Align` popover).

Answer (score 18):

Just faced the situation in which the bottom constraint was being *pinned* to the `Bottom Layout Guide` (a TabBar, in my case) instead of to the `superview`, as I wanted.

After tinkering around with programmatically created and or modified constraints, I found that you could actually do it through **Autolayout's Pin Popover**, just by selecting `View` instead of `Bottom Layout Guide` in the drop down that appears if you clic on the little arrow of the constraint's textfield.

That was, probably, not very clear, so here:

[image]

Comment: The answer seems not very related to the question, but solved my another problem and save my life! Thank you so much!